# Probability puzzle about zombies

Tags: time-series, probability, epidemiology

I am thinking about writing a simple game about zombies. I got stuck trying to calculate how many people should become zombies.

**Here are my conditions:**
We have a small rural town of 700 people. One night 200 zombies come to town. Each zombie has a single 30% contact chance (per day) with 50% chance of infection of one human and turning him into a new zombie. How many people shall become zombies on the **first**, **second** and **third** day?

I decided to leverage the chance of infection according to amount of people in town. The more people, the less chance for contact (which may look controversial, yet let it be so). So `(200/700)*0.3=0.086` or `8.6%` contact chance. 
Then I started off thinking that one zombie has `8.6%` chance of infecting one human and during one day there shall be 200 tries per 200 humans only. I tried to find a number of tries at which the probability of infection is 99.9% and it appears to be 60. Then every ~60th human shall be infected which means `700/60=11.6` people per day. I don't have any background in statistics so I am probably wrong, it would be nice if anyone would help me.

Comment: The solution depends on your assumptions about how zombies interact with people: the interpretation of the 30% daily chance hinges on that. Could you elaborate on how you would like that value of 30% to be interpreted? For instance, if there is one zombie and 1,000 people, are you expecting 0.3 infections or 300 infections?  What if there are 1,000 zombies and one person--will that person be infected with a chance of 30% or something different?

Comment: In infectious diseases epidemiology the infection path usually has two parameters: virulence and contact rate. Virulence is how likely a person will get infected upon a single contact, and contact rate is frequency of contacts. Your 30% is currently unclear... if it's virulence, holding contact at 1 person/day, then there should be 200*0.3, if it's contact rate is 30% of the people with a virulence of 100%... then I guess the town is going to be over pretty soon.

Comment: +1 for mentioning zombies. This paper might help you: modelling infection in a zombie outbreak  http://www.mathstat.uottawa.ca/~rsmith/Zombies.pdf Also has code.

Comment: @whuber♦ @Penguin_Knight I modified my conditions according to your suggestions.

Comment: Check this comprehensive paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01104

Comment: all the views because of the word zombie :p

Comment: Despite the zombies, I decide to vote to close this question because the conditions/interpretations are not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually written two papers on zombie epidemiology, so this is a question near and dear to my heart.

One suggestion I have is to use a dynamic model to estimate this, rather than just a time series (this is the technique used by the Smith? (the question mark is part of his name) paper).

There's a good site for tinkering with some of the parameters you've suggested that's the result of a paper I worked on: https://www.cartwrig.ht/apps/whitezed/

Comment: Perhaps you have a clearer idea than the original proposer concerning what the conditions of this game are?  I still cannot find an unambiguous way of interpreting the question.

Comment: @whuber My *reading* of the question is a SI model with S = 700, I = 200, and a beta parameter of -0.3 log (1-0.5)

Comment: Whats an SI model?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen susceptible-infected model. One of the standard compartmental models used in mathematical epidemiology.